# How to make a dynamic LazyVGrid of custom WebViews with SwiftUI (macOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, wkwebview

I'm currently developing an app that shows the code for different SwiftUI files in a single column. I'm using multiple WKWebView instances to display each file (for easy hosting + built-in syntax highlighting support). The WebViews are sized to fit the container with padding:

[image: Screenshot: Single column layout]

For some of the larger projects – with numerous files – I'm attempting to implement a [LazyVGrid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid) that would display the smaller, supporting files side-by-side as such:

[image: Screenshot: Double column layout]

### The Issue

However, I have been unable to get the grid to resize into a single-column when the window is made smaller (or even into a 3-column if the user is using a super-wide monitor; although, this is much less of a priority). Is a LazyVGrid the best way to go about this, or should I be taking a different approach? I feel like I'm so close.

**GridLayout.swift**

```
struct GridLayout: View {
  let data: [String]
  enum dataType { case title; case url }
  let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
  
  func get(_ forType: dataType, _ string: String) -> String {
    if forType == .title { return string.components(separatedBy: "*")[0] }
    if forType == .url { return string.components(separatedBy: "*")[1] }
    return ""
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(data, id: \.self) { i in
          CodeView(title: get(.title, i), height: 500, url: get(.url, i))
          .frame(minWidth: 300, idealWidth: 400, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this with a `GeometryReader`. Here I’m using `.flexible()` grid items but varying the number of columns based on the overall width of the parent view: if the width is under 800px, do 1 column; if the width is between 800 and 1200px, do 2 columns; otherwise do 3 columns.

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        let gridItem = GridItem(.flexible())
        var columnCount: Int = {
            switch geometry.size.width {
            case 0..<800:
                return 1
            case 800..<1200:
                return 2
            default:
                return 3
            }
        }()
        
        LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: gridItem,
                                 count: columnCount)) {
            ForEach(1..<5) { _ in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(height: 500)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the dynamic LazyVGrid working using [this reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/heebgz/how_to_make_the_new_lazyvgrid_column_count_dynamic/) from r/SwiftUI. I have been unable to limit the grid to two-columns; however, I have gotten the dynamic grid working with the the following modifications to the code:

```
struct DoubleLayout: View {
  ...

  private let size: CGFloat = 300  // min width
  
  private var columns: [GridItem] {
    return [
      .init(.adaptive(minimum: size, maximum: .infinity))
    ]
  }
  
  var body: some View {
      LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(data, id: \.self) { i in
          CodeView(title: get(.title, i), height: 500, url: get(.url, i))
            .frame(minWidth: 300, idealWidth: 400, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would still be interested on how to limit the layout to 2-columns.